# Can I get debug symbols for flash player? Or any other way to get support for flash?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, crash, flash, debug-symbols

The company I am working for has a flash component (using flex and cs4) that crashes intermittently in chrome, FF and IE.  (so far only win32 platforms)

I submitted a bug report to Adobe but have not heard anything back from them.  Their support process seems like a black hole.  WE can get a dump from Flash using [these steps](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408620.html#makecase) but after submitting the bug we got no help at all.

We loaded this into MS visual studio but can;t get decent stack information because there are no symbols for the flash stuff.

Microsoft and other companies provide symbols to help with debugging and we would like to get that from adobe.  Is there any way to make progress on this?

Does anyone know where to get flash symbols or how else we can make progress?

It is hard to debug the process if the container just dies.

the binary is 
flash10c.ocx

I just spent a painful hour on the phone with adobe folks - and the final answer from one of them (I spoke to about 8 people) was that they do not have a per incident purchase plan for developer support for flash.

I find that hard to believe.

Does anyone know how to get support for Flash?

Comment: What is "A flash component"? Is it the Flash player, or a wrapper around it? Do you ask it to do special things?

Comment: I'm not the flash developer, but we write code for the flash player to play/run.   http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/?view=gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Flash Player crash when allocating to large/many bitmaps when using `cacheAsBitmap`. There are probably hundreds of reasons why Flash Player can crash, but if you are using `cacheAsBitmap`, try turning it off and see if it helps..

Comment: it is audio related. We thought initially it was from memory issues - but now we think it is some odd packets and some library inability to handle them.  Adobe won't provide the debug symbols.